# Force empty <span> to next line when wrapping occurs

Tags: html, css, whitespace, line-breaks, trailing-whitespace

The following snippet generates for me this result:

[image]

(**The `border`s are just a quick way to easily show all the elements, including the `<span>`s containing the space as well as the empty `<span>`s. They are not part of the solution**)

My aim is to have the first `foo` to stay on the line it is, and the second `foo` to be at the following line.

If the "space" `<span>` in the middle keeps occupying no space, it's not important where it is (after the `foo` on the first line or before the `foo` on the second line); but if it does end up showing as an actual space, then I definitely want it at the end of the first line.

```css
:root {
  font-size: 3em;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10rem;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.foo {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span> </span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span class="foo"></span><!--
--><span> </span><!--
--><span class="foo"></span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span>
</div>
```

---

In my usecase, there's only one `foo` at any given time (in practice, that `<span class="foo"></span>` is moved around), but I've shown both for simplicity. After all, I don't exclude that at some point I might want to show multiple of those.

Comment: *In my usecase, there's only one foo at any given time, but I've shown both for simplicity.* --> this is not simplicity if you are showing a different use case. Most of the answers will consider the code with 2 .foo and you will end with inaccurate answers

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I've clarified.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `float: left` on the spans and `clear: left;` on the second `.foo` using `.foo ~ .foo` as a selector for that:

```css
:root {
  font-size: 3em;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10rem;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
}
.foo {
  border-color: red;
}
.foo ~ .foo {
  clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span> </span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span class="foo"></span><!--
--><span> </span><!--
--><span class="foo"></span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span>
</div>
```

Comment: [This also reduces a lot all the `<span> </span>`s, at the point that as soon as I remove the `border`s, all the text seems one single long word.](https://jsfiddle.net/Enrico89/wc9p4urn/5/)

Comment: @Enlico Yes, but that's already the case in the code of your question. A span is an inline element by default.

Comment: I don't see the same spacing in your snippet and in mine.

Comment: @Enlico I do... (on Firefox)

Comment: [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93HLM.png) is what I see on Chromium. Is it different from Firefox?

Comment: No, apart from a slightly different font. But the "spacing" inside the spans looks the same as in the snippet you have in the question.

Comment: The only thing where there is different spaing is in the empty spans.

Comment: No, it's the spans with just a whitespace in it too. As soon as you remove the 2 `border: 1px solid black;`, every  `<span> </span>` is 0x0, which is not the case in my example.

Comment: sorry, that's what I meant by "empty spans"

Comment: Anyway, your question was: "My aim is to have the first foo to stay on the line it is, and the second foo to be at the following line." So that's what I focused on, and in fact, I gave you a solution for this question... If you need something else, you really need to describe it better, sorry.

Comment: I disagree. Your answer may address the main point the question is about, but it does so at the expense of changing the layout for every element in the example.

Comment: Also, if you cherry pick pieces of the question and decide that's the only thing to consider, then another solution could have been _"Oh, just put `display: block;` in the `span {}` ruleset and add `.foo + span {
  display: initial; }`"_, because that too causes "the first foo to stay on the line it is, and the second foo to be at the following line". But would you have called it a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Like [the other deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77340086/5825294), the answer below assumes that one knows which a `<span>`s containing just the space are indeed the trailing element on that visual line.

Luckily, I have that information at hand, because I already have in place some JavaScript logic that puts the `foo` right before the line wraps.

---

Just a bit of JavaScript to stick `display: flex;` to the trailing space seems to do the trick, leading to the desired result:

[image]

I tend to look at it as a sub-optimal solution, because it uses JavaScript, so I'll wait for other answers.

```js
let div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
// or any other way to get the parent of the <span>s
let findLastFoo = e => e.findLastIndex(s => s.classList.contains('foo'));
// or any other way to get the <span class="foo"></span> to be sent to newline

div.children[findLastFoo(Array.from(div.children)) - 1].classList.add('trailing-space');
```

```css
:root {
  font-size: 3em;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 10rem;
}
span {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.foo {
  border-color: red;
}

.trailing-space {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
<span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span> </span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span class="foo"></span><!--
--><span> </span><!--
--><span class="foo"></span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span><!--
--><span>a</span>
</div>
```